# Is there a solution to the error: The method 'validate' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a solution to the error: The method 'validate' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

My Code

```
onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          dynamic result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                          if(result == null){
                            setState(() => error = 'Could not sign in with those credentials.');
                          }
                        }
                      }
```

formKey is a global key

```
  final _formKey =  GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Comment: try "if (_formKey.currentState!.validate())"

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) ...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You just copy/pasted a comment from 2 months ago. While it may answer the question, please provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question, so that it improves its long-term value.